# Issue with Filtering on Column "Text Does not Equal" not Working as Expected

Tags: excel, filter

In Column A I have values like:

01

20

FX

When I add a filter to this column where text does not equal FX it works fine.
However if I try to filter where text does not equal 01, or where text does not equal 20 it doesn't filter out these rows!

If I filter where text equals 01, or text equals 20 it works as expected!!

I'm actually trying to apply this filter within a Macro, but realized the issue is prevalent even when applying the filter within the Excel worksheet.

Many thanks in advance to any help received!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the 01 and 20 values were "text stored as numbers"

If you highlight the desired Range in Excel, then click the Data Tab and select Text to Columns and press "Finish" it will convert the Text to Numbers and the filter will then work as expected.

To do this in VBA you can use the following:

```
Range.TextToColumns
```